# Why does pipeline parameter cause error when combined with PSDefaultParameterValues?

Tags: powershell

My powershell function should accept a list of valid paths of mixed files and/or directories either as a named parameter or via pipeline, filter for files that match a pattern, and return the list of files.

`$Paths = 'C:\MyFolder\','C:\MyFile'`

This works: `Get-Files -Paths $Paths` This doesn't: `$Paths | Get-Files`

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    "Get-Files:Paths"   = ( Get-Location ).Path
}

[regex]$DateRegex = '(20\d{2})([0-1]\d)([0-3]\d)'
[regex]$FileNameRegex = '^term2-3\.7_' + $DateRegex + '\.csv$' 

Function Get-Files {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.IO.FileInfo[]])]
    [OutputType([System.IO.FileInfo])]
    param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false, # Should default to $cwd provided by $PSDefaultParameterValues
            ValueFromPipeline,
            HelpMessage = "Enter filesystem paths that point either to files directly or to directories holding them."
        )]
        [String[]]$Paths
    )
    begin {
        [System.IO.FileInfo[]]$FileInfos = @()
        [System.IO.FileInfo[]]$SelectedFileInfos = @()
    }
    process { foreach ($Path in $Paths) {
        Switch ($Path) {
            { Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType leaf } {
                $FileInfos += (Get-Item $Path)
            }
            { Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType container } {
                foreach ($Child in (Get-ChildItem $Path -File)) {
                    $FileInfos += $Child
                }
            }
            Default {
                Write-Warning -Message "Path not found: $Path"
                continue
            }
        }
        $SelectedFileInfos += $FileInfos | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $FileNameRegex }
        $FileInfos.Clear()
    } }
    end {
        Return $SelectedFileInfos | Get-Unique
    }
}
```

I found that both versions work if I remove the default parameter value. Why?

Why does passing a parameter via the pipeline cause an error when that parameter has a default defined in PSDefaultParameterValues, and is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Is the error `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`? Handling pipeline input is the _last_ step performed by the parameter binder, so if a matching `$PSDefaultParameterValues` entry exists for the parameter, it will have already been bound by the time the pipeline input reaches the command. Effectively, the default value turns your call into `$Paths |Get-Files -Paths ( Get-Location ).Path`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's happening here?!

This is a timing issue.

PowerShell attempts to bind and process parameter arguments in *roughly** the following order:

1. Explicitly *named* parameter arguments are bound (eg. `-Param $value`)
2. *Positional* arguments are bound (`abc` in `Write-Host abc`)
3. **Default parameter values are applied for any parameter that wasn't processed during the previous two steps** - note that applicable `$PSDefaultParameterValues` *always* take precedence over defaults defined in the parameter block
4. Resolve parameter set, validate all mandatory parameters have values (this only fails if there are no upstream command in the pipeline)
5. Invoke the `begin {}` blocks on all commands in the pipeline
6. For any commands downstream in a pipeline: wait for input and then start binding it to the most appropriate parameter that **hasn't been handled in previous steps**, and invoke `process {}` blocks on all commands in the pipeline

As you can see, the value you assign to `$PSDefaultParameterValues` takes effect in step 3 - long before PowerShell even has a chance to start binding the piped string values to `-Paths`, in step 6.

*) this is a gross over-simplification, but the point remains: default parameter values must have been handled *before* pipeline binding starts.

---

#### How to work around it?

Given the procedure described above, we should be able to work around this behavior by explicitly *naming* the parameter we want to bind the pipeline input to.

But how do you combine `-Paths` with pipeline input?

By supplying a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) (or a "pipeline-bound parameter expression" as they're sometimes called):

```
$Paths | Get-Files -Paths { $_ }
```

This will cause PowerShell to recognize `-Paths` during step 1 above - at which point the default value assignment is *skipped*.

Once the command starts receiving input, it *transforms* the input value and binds the resulting value to `-Paths`, by executing the `{ $_ }` block - since we just output the item as-is, the effect is the exact same as when the pipeline input is bound implicitly.

---

#### Digging deeper

If you want to learn more about what happens "behind the curtain", the best tool available is `Trace-Command`:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Get-Files:Paths'] = $PWD

Trace-Command -Expression { $Paths |Get-Files } -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost
```

I should mention that the `ParameterBinding` tracer is *very verbose* - which is great for surmising what's going on - but the output can be a bit overwhelming, in which case you might want to replace the `-PSHost` parameter with `-PSPath .\path\to\output.txt` to write the trace output to a file

Answer (score 4):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

- **A parameter that is bound via an entry in the dictionary stored in the [`$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psdefaultparametervalues) is bound *before* it is potentially bound *via the pipeline***, just like passing a parameter value *explicitly*, *as an argument* would.
- **Once a given parameter is bound that way, it cannot be bound *again* via the *pipeline*, causing an error**:

  - `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`
  - As you can see, the specific problem at hand - a parameter *already being bound* - is unfortunately *not* covered by this message. The unspoken part is that once a given parameter has been bound *by argument* (possibly via `$PSDefaultParameterValues`), it is removed from the set of *candidate* pipeline-binding parameters the input could bind to, and if there are no candidates remaining, the error occurs.
- **The only way to override a `$PSDefaultParameterValue` preset value is to use an (explicit) *argument***.

[This comment on a related GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14701#issuecomment-773476552) provides details on the order of parameter binding.

A simplified way to reproduce the problem:

```
& { 

  # Preset the -Path parameter for Get-Item
  # In any later Get-Item calls that do not use -Path explicitly, this
  # is the same as calling Get-Item -Path /
  $PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ 'Get-Item:Path' = '/' }

  # Trying to bind the -Path parameter *via the pipeline* now fails,
  # because it has already been bound via $PSDefaultParameterValues.
  # Even without the $PSDefaultParameterValues entry in the picture,
  # you'd get the same error with: '.' | Get-Item -Path /
  '.' | Get-Item 

  # By contrast, using an *argument* allows you to override the preset.
  Get-Item -Path .
}
```